# Need help in changing layout at run time using Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .Net.
Currently working on creating a bus layout for a online bus reservation system.
is there any solution possible with  below code

**1. Booking.aspx file**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="SeatLayout" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate><table class="seatList"><tr></HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <td>
          <input type="image" 
                  src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" ><%# Eval("NumberSeat")%></input>
          </td>
        </ItemTemplate>

     <FooterTemplate></tr></table></FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

**2. Databinding in codebehind file.**

```
SeatLayout.DataSource = _seatBUS.GetAllSeatByBusRouter(_listBus);
SeatLayout.DataBind();
```

**3. Data source involves "Seat" table which has columns like**

```
SeatID
NumberSeat
Status
ListBusId
```

Comment: What is your problem with the existing code?

Comment: I'm confused here. What is the problem/question? Your question is pretty vague.

Comment: All Seat are rendered one by one in browser,but i want to render each input image as if it is top view of bus and not as serially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

1. Create the bus image using a basic bus background and a bunch of
   smaller images of the various seats in the bus.
2. Position the seats
       in their respective locations using CSS absolute positioning.
3. Change the seat image depending on the NumberSeat returned by the
           datasource.

I'm not sure what your bus image looks like, but you may even be able to use divs instead of seat images, which would lighten the server load and allow you to simply change the background color of the appropriate div ID instead of changing the image sources.

These tutorials should help you get started:

- [How to position divs absolutely using CSS](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-tips-how-to-use-absolute-position-property/)
- [How to use absolute positioning inside relative positioning.](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)
- [How to install JQuery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery)
- [How to change background color with jquery.](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: shall I use div to create bus image inside itemtemplate tag in above code ? and Also if I create bus image with smaller seats images, to which element datasource will be bound?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do, which I still don't fully understand. I will say this, you should try to avoid asp.net controls where you can. I'm not saying I don't use asp.net, I'm just saying most of what you need to do can be done with CSS, HTML, and jQuery/javascript. This keeps the server lightweight, allows for better customization, and keeps things client-side. You should probably start reading up on integrating those three with asp.net in order to pose a more concise question. Sorry I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: I am trying to create a simple bus seat layout here, like in http://www.travelyaari.com/

Comment: @user1933538, agree with lopsided - create a static layout with html/css where seats are divs. All you need is to change the class for available divs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if your request is for me to programmatically design a generalized bus route for you then I can't help you. The best I can do is send you in the right direction.