# How to make a CheckBox List behave like Radio Button in Vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Let me explain myself i'm doing an Application in VB.net asp.net and I Want to put a CheckBox List instead of Radio Button cause my customer want it square and not round. The Only problem i got is when i check a Checkbox the other one are not unchecked. I'm not sure im clear enough feel free to ask me question.

Comment: A short answer: This is not the default behavior of checkboxes. Radios are for single selections, checks are for multiple.  If you'd like to restrict your checkboxes to one selection, you'll have to use Javascript for that.

Comment: This is inherently a bad idea. Checkboxes are recognizable as a boolean selection, while circular radio buttons are known for a one-of-many selection. Doing this will just confuse the end-user who expects a boolean choice but finds checkboxes performing a one-of-many choice.

Comment: Like I said I do not have the choice. They want it like this. Matt you have any idea how i could do that i'm really new to JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen above, this isn't recommended. However if you have to do it, here's how I made it in jQuery:

Create your checkboxes and assign them classes

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbr"/>CB 1
<input type="checkbox" class="cbr"/>CB 2
<input type="checkbox" class="cbr"/>CB 3
<input type="checkbox" class="cbr"/>CB 4
<input type="checkbox" class="cbr"/>CB 5
```

And the jQuery

```
$(".cbr").click(function() {
    $(".cbr").prop("checked", false);
    this.checked = true;
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g2YMs/

Also, if you're creating the checkboxes with ASP.NET controls, you should select them using:

```
$("#<%=IdOfControl.ClientID%>")
```

This is, of course, if you decide to go the jQuery way.

Comment: Ok this seems good but I've never use Jquery before where do i put it in my code?

Comment: Here's a nice guide to getting started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery -- Good luck with everything!

Comment: OK i've done what they say but the problem is it say that the class cbr is not defined

Comment: You have to adjust the code to fit your needs. The cbr class is something I defined in each radio button, you can define cbr as your class, or anything you want with the `class` attribute.

Comment: OK I've finnaly found the way to do it thank you very much for your time