# Only one checkbox checked at a time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have `3` checkbox, for which I want only `1` checkbox to be checked at a time. below is my fiddle for the html

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n03jLhqa/)

I want this to be worked in `IE8` also kindly suggest how to do

Comment: _"I want only 1 checkbox to be checked at a time"_, if you want that then why not use radio buttons which have that functionality built in

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I know it has inbuilt functionality of that,. But the client requirements is on the basis of `checkbox` :(

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548041/how-to-make-a-checkbox-list-behave-like-radio-button-in-vb-net.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: same issue, not working. I am able to check all the checkboxes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQM8k/1094/):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" />

$('input.chk').on('change', function() {
    $('input.chk').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

***Edit:***
for second part of your question to `un-check other checkboxes when selecting parent checkbox` see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpr8hby4) - (as per chat) :

```
if (!cb.checked) { 
$('#trchkOptions input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false); 
}
```

Comment: You need Jquery included also make sure your checkboxes are not asp.net as it will change the ID, if it is set it to static. see fiddle, if pure Javascript then see Gokul's answer

Comment: if you click on it will tell you where the error is you must have included something like extra  >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110902/discussion-between-coder-and-zaki).

Comment: hi check chat room

Comment: Thanku so much Zaki.!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function selectOnlyThis(id) {
    for (var i = 1;i <= 4; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(i).checked = false;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 3
<input type="checkbox" id="4" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 4
```

It should help you

Comment: I get error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object`