# Automatically reload a page after uploading a file

Tags: jquery, dropbox, reload

Following the answers [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15864618) I was able to produce a very satisfactory job. It's almost perfect. I'm trying to make a kind of warning panel loading news from a `txt` file on my Dropbox Public folder. So I just update that file and its content is shown on my page.

I have two files to produce this result. The important codes are:

### pag01.html

Load the file `avisos.html` which I use to format the contents from the data file containing the updated news.

```
<div id="quadro" class="avisos">
<script>
  var url = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42709342/avisos.html';

// 3. ok got the data
function afterReadFromDropBox(data) {
$('#quadro').html(data);
}

// 2. ok the document is ready, lets grab some data from dropbox
function whenDocumentIsReady(){
$.get(url, afterReadFromDropBox );
}

// 1. when document is ready make the call
$(document).ready( whenDocumentIsReady );
</script>
</div>
```

### avisos.html

Just load the data file `avisos` from my Dropbox Public folder.

```
<div id="avisosmsg" class="avisosmsg">
<script>
   var url = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42709342/avisos';

// 3. ok got the data
function afterReadFromDropBox(data) {
$('#avisosmsg').html(data);
}

// 2. ok the document is ready, lets grab some data from dropbox
function whenDocumentIsReady(){
$.get(url, afterReadFromDropBox );
}

// 1. when document is ready make the call
$(document).ready( whenDocumentIsReady );
</script>
</div>
```

During my tests I use the tag

```
<meta  http-equiv="Refresh" Content=2; url="pag01.html">
```

to reload the page automatically and avoid pressing F5 a lot of times.

**So here is my question:** *how to do a code to reload automatically every time I upload a new version of my data file to Dropbox. Is it possible to do a kind of standby procedure?*

**ps:** I'm also having problem with encoding as you can see on the image below showing a part of my page with my warning panel.

[image]

Comment: I'd have thought the easiest way would be to poll your dropbox folder with Ajax now and again and check the file date and time based on the previous date and time

Comment: @griegs, thanks for your attention, but I have no idea how to do this. I need to learn from the beginning. Thanks again.