# Need to hide <tr> by name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to hide tr by attribute name here is the code

```
<tr name="see items ordered">
<td>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried the below code but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xyz = document.getElementsByName("see items ordered");
xyz[0].style.display="none";
</script>
```

If is there any way using js,jquery or css to hide by name attribute please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be working, you are probably try to access before elements added to DOM, use document.ready to ensure element get added to DOM. Or but the script just before the body ending tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/wYAM4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xyz = document.getElementsByName("see items ordered");
    xyz[0].style.display="none";
});
```

or, putting it just before ending body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var xyz = document.getElementsByName("see items ordered");
   xyz[0].style.display="none";
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Im getting xyz[0] is undefined when im adding this code <script type="text/javascript">
   var xyz = document.getElementsByName("see items ordered");
   xyz[0].style.display="none";
 </script>

Comment: This is because the getElementsByName did not return the object you are looking for, did you put code in document.ready? or just before ending body tag? as suggested in answer

Comment: Did you include jQuery for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery

Comment: yes but getting error Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"

Comment: Can you just put script tag just just before body ending tag as suggested in answer

Comment: Its netsuite website my account page

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code in dom ready handler. also can use name-value selector to target the tr:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr[name="see items ordered"]').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS solution using attribute selector.

this selector will look the `see` word. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xawuneba/1/edit)**.

```
tr[name~="see"]
{color:green;}
```

See the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: any specific browser you are looking for?

Comment: I change the color text only to show that it will work. if you will use `display:none;` the text will hide.

Comment: I've also included a screenshot as well here.

Comment: No its not working i need to apply it on see items ordered...not on only see word

Comment: your question was misguided as Question says  `hide by using name attribute`. can you share what text you are using for `name attribute` for visible items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3K8Ft/

```
<table>
    <tr name="see items ordered">
        <td>
            Test 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Test 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName("see items ordered");
xyz[0].style.display="none";
```