# Select div in jquery through id in variable

Tags: jquery, html

How to select a div in jquery using id. That id which is store in variable.

```
<div id="d3">
  some thing is here...
</div>
```

jquery Code:

```
var id = 3;
$("#d" + id)
```

I am using this code but this is not working.

Comment: you code i fine it should work if jquery is included and its document.ready

Comment: Create a `jsFiddle` to show us your code in place.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/29N6U/

Answer (score 3):

This i working.

Example:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/PzYSG/)

HTML:

```
<div id="d3">
  some thing is here...
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var id = 3;
$("#d" + id).html("Change it!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and getting the element by the selector check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW5D/), you need to check following.

- jQuery is added, see how to [add/install jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery).
- Your code gets executed with dom is ready, use [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW5D/)

```
var id = 3;
alert($("#d" + id).html()); // shows some thing is here... in alert.
```

Comment: No this code is not working. jquery is added and I am using it in dom ready.Please check yourself

Comment: @user3672518 Who should check it is you, not someone who's trying to help you. Check the comments in your question. There's a `jsFiddle` link with the actual code working.

Comment: When you say "Your code is correct", the existing code does nothing you can see (it just obtains a JQuery element then discards it) :)

Comment: The statement "this is not working" does not gives any clear hint that what is happening? you might be getting some error that can help in finding the solution

Comment: I check the console and it give error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #d4" "

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select a div here is the code,If i understand your correctly your want to select the text  some thing is here...?

```
<div id="d3">
  some thing is here...
</div>

$(function() {
    var id = 3;
    $("#d3" + id);
});
```