# Additional Navigation bar on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar with the section "Contracts" and I was wondering if it were possible, and how would I go about adding an additional navigation bar to expand underneath when this button is tagged, (For example, on the Apple Store site, when you click a product, this adds another bar)

[image: Apple Navigation Bar]

I can provide my entire CSS style sheet if needed! I think this will require JavaScript but I'm trying to keep it as pure CSS for now!

All help is greatly appreciated!

HTML Code: This is the Navigation HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="title">
        <img src="img/logo2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li style="float: left"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contracts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#other">Other</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#release">Release Notes</a></li>
            <li> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.phpartnership.com">Pinnacle Health Partnership</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Creates this

[image: My nav bar]

CSS Code: My entire stylesheet

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #333;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 .navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 4px;
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
    transition-property: left, right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.navbar li:hover:before, navbar li:focus:before, .navbar li:active:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
    padding: 25px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
    height: 80px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.home {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px !important;
}
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right_col {
    float: right;
   width: 50%;
}
.right_col img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.left_col img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This is the JavaScript I tried to use to hide and show the div on click

```
<script>
$(index.php).ready(function(){
    ``$("#contract").click(function(){
            $("<div class="contracts">").toggle();
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please share your code ( html, css ) so we can give you a good solution.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question with them both!

Comment: try again :) still not seeing the code

Comment: Had to edit it because it was a tad long! Sorry for that

Comment: I've also included an image of what my Navigation bar looks like

Comment: well have you tried a solution to your question by yourself ?

Comment: I originally began to look at hiding and showing a div depending on an "on click" event, but it hasn't seemed to work

Comment: I've added the JavaScript I'm trying to use as well

Comment: Where is your contracts class div? and this `$("<div class="contracts">").toggle();` should be `$(".contracts").toggle();`

Comment: posted an answer with 3 different solutions. check them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess you want smth like this : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/rmoax7zu/)**

first add jQuery to your local environment 
use this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

add it in the `head` section of your html. for more info check [how to install jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery)

added html inside the `.navbar`

```
<ul class="aditional">
     <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
      <li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

added css :

```
.aditional {
position:absolute;
top:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000;
display:none;
}
.aditional li {
color:#fff;
}
```

added js :

```
$('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2) a').click(function() {
          $(".aditional").slideToggle()
});
```

**OR if you want a more responsive solution**

**check this :[jsfiddle with target](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/rmoax7zu/2/)**

use `data-target` on the `li a` like this

```
<li><a href="#contact" data-target="contracts">Contracts</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" data-target="aboutus">About Us</a></li>
```

added html :

```
 <ul class="aditional contracts">
     <li>test1</li>
     <li>test2</li>
     <li>test3</li>
     <li>test4</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="aditional aboutus">
      <li>about</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>about</li>
 </ul>
```

jq added :

```
$('.navbar ul li a').click(function() {
  $(".aditional").slideUp()
  var target = '.' + $(this).data('target');
  $(target).slideDown();
})
```

**OR** u can target the `href` of the `li a`. simply add this

```
<li><a href="#contract">Contracts</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
------
<ul class="aditional" id ="contract">
....
<ul class="aditional" id ="about">
....
```

and js :

```
$('.navbar ul li a').click(function() {
$(".aditional").slideUp()
var target = $(this).attr('href');
$(target).slideDown();

})
```

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/rmoax7zu/3/)**

one of these solutions should work for you . let me know

Comment: I love the top one, the only issue is that it doesn't seem to work for me even though I have the identical copy of the JSFiddle

Comment: be sure to activate jQuery in your jsfiddle. 
plus you can post it here so i can see what's wrong

Comment: I pasted my entire code into the Fiddle and it works there, but not for my local environment lol this has thrown me into confusion

Comment: inspect element and see in console if there is an error .

also be sure you have the jQuery library loaded. if it works in jsFiddle then my answer is correct. you should check your local settings.

.check the html and css on your local environment . be sure everything is in the right place

Comment: I got it to a point where It's always there, but it doesn't show and hide on click

Comment: And the error I'm getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: that's because you don't have jQuery added to your local environment 
use this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> `

add it in the `head` section of your html. for more info check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery

Comment: Okay JQuery has been added and it's there, but the section still won't show and hide on click, also getting 0 errors which is strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115954/discussion-between-mihai-t-and-jamie-belcher).