# What well known JavaScript libraries are located on CDN's, and what are the URLs'?

Tags: javascript, performance, scalability, cdn

It's pretty common knowledge that JQuery is in both the Microsoft and Google CDN, but there are more and more I'm hearing about such as Yahoo YAPI and others.

I'm a new web developer and am interested in hearing about what libraries are widely used, located on a CDN, and worth learning about.  What libraries would you recommend?

Comment: Made this a community wiki to encourage the posting of more URLs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google hosts a few more than jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/), so it's a pretty good CDN resource:

- [Dojo](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#dojo)
- [Ext Core](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#ext-core)
- [jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)
- [jQuery UI](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)
- [MooTools](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#mootools)
- [Prototype](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#prototype)
- [script.aculo.us](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#script_aculo_us)

Another benefit of Google's that's not as publicized as it should be is it hosts most previous versions and lets your access it in a number of ways, for example:

- jQuery 1.4.2: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js
- Latest 1.4.x: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js
- Latest 1.x.x: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js
- jQuery 1.3.2: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js

And another not-so-publicized feature is they host jQuery UI **and** the CSS/images for all the base themes, [there's a question on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/jquery-css-download-from-google), just change the version numbers in the URL to match the library version you're using.

Comment: I think you need to make more mention of jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the note about the jquery ui css/images. Good to know.

Comment: @michael - jQuery UI is the only visual library on there that's hosted in this way AFAIK...as for the version numbers, it applies to **all libraries** jQuery was just an example since I know the versions off the top of my head.

Comment: oh, I was trying to be funny. but failing. badly.

Answer (score 2):

Library is up to you. jQuery has a lot of momentum and Microsoft have adopted it, so I'd say it is a good contender.

Google [hosts quite a few libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/).

The Microsoft CDN is not as good, as it doesn't use its own domain, so you may end up with cookie data from the Microsoft site being passed around.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about CDNs in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447184/microsoft-cdn-for-jquery-or-google-cdn).