# Using javascript to check which CDN jQuery is cached from on the client

Tags: jquery

Can I use JavaScript to check whether JQuery is (already) downloaded (cached) on the target web browser (user) or not? For Example:

```
If (JQuery-from-Microsoft-CDN-downloaded)
    Then use http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js
Else if (JQuery-from-Google-APIs- downloaded)
    Then use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
Else if (JQuery-from-code.jquery.com- downloaded)
    Then use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Else use jQuery from my own website.
```

Means that using the ability of javascript to check whether one of them is downloaded on the target User (Web Browser), if not then use jQuery from my own website otherwise if true then use that version of JQuery that is downloaded on the target User.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think this is possible without actually loading the libraries. Although, it might be doable using an Ajax call and checking whether that returns a `304 not modified`.... Not sure whether this is practical though.

Comment: How does a user "download" something on the target browser?

Comment: @Luca he means whether the library in question is already cached

Comment: Yeah I meant that the library is already chached (from any server) and I want to use that cached library...

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1447184/102441)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this, another case where the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents any mechanism to accomplish this.  If you think about it, it makes sense...any mechanism you could use to accomplish this, you could *also* use to figure out which sites someone visited, by seeing which files they have cached.

Comment: It is my idea to use the power of javascript (of the web-browser) to use cached librares (by dynamic selection)

Comment: @Hazro - I understand your idea/goal, but it's not possible...it'd be a serious privacy breach if something like this were allowed.  Unfortunately there's no generic way to do this that wouldn't *also* allow it to be used for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to check if jQuery is loaded

```
var isLoaded = (jQuery) ? true : false;
```

or

```
var isLoaded = (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') ? false : true;
```

If your script is loaded inside same document that jQuery included you can parse DOM and check if any of the SCRIPT tag containing link to any of the CDN's

```
var jQueryVersion = isLoaded ? jQuery.fn.jquery : false;
```

Comment: This will only tell you which version you've downloaded from the script tag's source url - not what has been previously cached from other page views