# Dojo, dgrid define is not defined

Tags: javascript, dojo, undefined, dgrid

I am new to dojo and dgrid. I was following the tutorial on the site but I have two errors

`Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined dojo.js:1`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined index.html:10`

I copied the code from http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/hello_dgrid/ and changed the folder name as it was said.

The files are in the right place and I can't find the problem.
Maybe I need to change something in the dojo files.

```
<script src="dojodatagrid\dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script>
    require(["dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], 
    function(Grid){
        var data = [
            { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
            { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
            { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
        ];

        var grid = new Grid({
            columns: {
                first: "First Name",
                last: "Last Name",
                age: "Age"
            }
        }, "grid");
        grid.renderArray(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I believe your script's `src` attribute should be `src="dojodatagrid/dojo.js".`

Comment: Do you include `claro.css`?  Sometimes I forget that and the grid does not render.

Comment: @Jessemon i forgot to include it but it didn't solved the problem ;) i followed the tutorial and there was nothing said from any css.

For the path : i tried both and they both work :) but  the errors stay

Comment: Try using a CDN for a test, `<script data-dojo-config="async: 1"
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`.

Comment: @MatthiasDeSchoenmacker, I'm glad!  I changed my comment into a proper answer.  Please accept it.  By the way, there is some debate as to whether a CDN should be used in a production site or not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447184/microsoft-cdn-for-jquery-or-google-cdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test, try using a CDN like this:

`<script data-dojo-config="async: 1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed dgrid using CPM inside dojodatagrid.
Your src must be **src="dojodatagrid/dojo/dojo.js"** and not **src="dojodatagrid/dojo.js"**

Comment: The first exception indicates that dojo.js _is_ being loaded, so the src must point to the right place